# Why didn't the main() goroutine block after adding the last value?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I have a code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func squares(c chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        num := <-c
        fmt.Println(num * num)
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("main() started")
    c := make(chan int)

    go squares(c)

    c <- 1
    c <- 2
    c <- 3
    c <- 3
    fmt.Println("main() stopped")
}
```

And the answer is:
main() started
1
4
9
main() stopped

Can you explain, why main goroutine didn't block after the last value, while I have unbuffered channel. I was waiting for this answer: 1, 4, 4, 9

I tried to add time.Sleep after the last value, and the program worked as expected

Comment: Why would it block *after* sending a value to the channel successfully? It can only block *before* sending when there's no reader on the other side and no space in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

After the line `go squares(c)` there are 2 concurrently running goroutines:

1. the main goroutine (the code in `main()`)
2. the second goroutine (the code in `squares()`

Each channel send operation (e.g. `c <- 1`) causes synchronization between the goroutines. But after the last send operation there is no more synchronization. Both goroutines run independently, although not for long.

If the line `fmt.Println("main() stopped")` in the main goroutine happens to run before the line `fmt.Println(num * num)` in the second goroutine (like in your case) then the `main()` function returns causing both goroutine to quit.

In order to ensure that the second goroutine finishes its work the main goroutine needs to wait for it. This can be done using another channel or a `WaitGroup`.